# Unable to Flight test Newsletter in AEM6

Tags: aem, newsletter

I am flight testing the newsletter.I have configured Day CQ Mail Service to use my company's SMTP server to send emails. But when clicking on Send button to test the Newsletter, I get the below error:-

Failed to send newsletter
Please activate the email before running this operation.

Is there any option in AEM from where we have to enable the mailing service first?

Answer (score 2):

I had also found the same error.
There is a misunderstanding when it ask to enable the mailing service.

You can Activate the newsletter (email newsletter you had made in campaign). Notice when activating, keep your publish up, otherwise, it won't activate.

It might work with this only.
But, you can also check your mailing configuration from [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/send-email-and-attach-filesimages-from-aem/)